# How to access "belongs_to" object in polymorphic associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having difficulty accessing a model in a "belongs_to" association. I have "post" and "comment" models that each can have many "likes." Right now, I can access

> comment.likes

or

> post.likes

but I get an "undefined method" if I try

> like.comment

I attempted to implement the Rails associations as follows:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Likeable

....

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Likeable
```

I have a "Likeable" module:

```
module Likeable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :likes, as: :likeable,
      class_name: "Like",
      dependent: :destroy
  end
```

My "Like" model looks partly as follows:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :author_id, presence: true, uniqueness: { scope: [:likeable_id, :likeable_type]}

  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
```

I believe everything is setup correctly on the database layer. How does the above Rails layer look?
Any suggestions/advice appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: It should be just `like.likeable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The whole idea of a polymorphic association is that from the `Like` side of things, you don't need to know what it's associated to in order to call that associated object.

Ie. you should access the associated object with just `like.likeable` and that will return either a `Comment` or a `Post` instance, depending on which one this `Like` is associated with.

Comment: I seem to get an undefined method error when trying to access via `like.likeable`... `undefined method 'likeable' for #<Like::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8d3b533b88>`

Comment: You've almost certainly done something like: `like = Like.where(something)`.  This returns the group AR_Relation object not an individual record.  Try changing your `where` to `find_by` - which returns the first record that matches the conditions.